# Easy way to add image to a element on a onclick event javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following html code.. 
Now i want to add an image (Say Alphabet image Q) to the element clicked..
I am new to javascript.. Please brief how we should do the same..

Thanks in advance..

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        8*8 Queen
    </title>
```

Below is the css code..

```
    <style>
        td {
            width:70px;
            height:70px;
            background-color:white;
            border:1px solid;
        }
        .black {
            background:black;
        }
        .white {
            background: white;
        }
        .red {
            background:red !important;
        }
    </style>
```

Below is the javascript code..

```
        //var window.boxFlag=new Array();
        //var window.i=0;
        var myEntry = new Array();



        function init() {
            for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {

                myEntry[i] = new Array();
                for (var j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
                    myEntry[i][j] = 0;
                }

            }


        }

        function removeQueen(domObj) {


        }
        function place(domObj, row, col) {


            var placeQueen = true;


            if (myEntry[row][col] == 1) {

                //if already added, remove entry
                myEntry[row][col] = 0;
                domObj.classList.toggle("red");

            } else {

                //New entry


                //column validate
                for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {

                    if (myEntry[i][col] == 1) {
                        placeQueen = false;
                        break;
                    }

                }

                //row validate
                for (var j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {

                    if(myEntry[row][j]==1){

                        placeQueen=false;
                        break;

                    }

                }

                //Diagonal validate

                for(var i=row-1,j=col-1;i>0&&j>0;i--,j--){

                    if(myEntry[i][j]==1){

                        placeQueen=false;
                        break;

                    }

                }



                for(var i=row+1,j=col+1;i<=8&&j<=8;i++,j++){

                    //alert(i);

                    if(myEntry[i][j]==1){

                        placeQueen=false;
                        break;

                    }

                }

                for(var i=row+1,j=col-1;i<=8&&j>0;i++,j--){


                    if(myEntry[i][j]==1){

                        placeQueen=false;
                        break;
                    }

                }

                for(var i=row-1,j=col+1;i>0&&j<=8;i--,j++){


                    if(myEntry[i][j]==1){

                        placeQueen=false;
                        break;

                    }

                }


                if (placeQueen) {
                    //on success
                    myEntry[row][col] = 1;
                    //set to true
                    domObj.classList.toggle("red");
                    //To toggle red with white/black
                }
                else {

                    alert("Not a proper place");

                }
            }


        }



    </script>
</head>
```

Html starts from body

```
<body onload="init();">

    <table> 
        <tr id="row1">
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 1, 1)">

            </td>
            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 1, 2)"></td>
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 1, 3)"></td>
            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 1, 4)"></td>
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 1, 5)"></td>
            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 1, 6)"></td>
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 1, 7)"></td>
            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 1, 8)"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="row2">

            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 2, 1)"></td>
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 2, 2)"></td>
            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 2, 3)"></td>
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 2, 4)"></td>
            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 2, 5)"></td>
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 2, 6)"></td>
            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 2, 7)"></td>
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 2, 8)"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="row3">
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 3, 1)"></td>
            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 3, 2)"></td>
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 3, 3)"></td>
            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 3, 4)"></td>
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 3, 5)"></td>
            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 3, 6)"></td>
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 3, 7)"></td>
            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 3, 8)"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="row4">

            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 4, 1)"></td>
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 4, 2)"></td>
            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 4, 3)"></td>
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 4, 4)"></td>
            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 4, 5)"></td>
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 4, 6)"></td>
            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 4, 7)"></td>
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 4, 8)"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="row5">
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 5, 1)"></td>
            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 5, 2)"></td>
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 5, 3)"></td>
            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 5, 4)"></td>
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 5, 5)"></td>
            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 5, 6)"></td>
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 5, 7)"></td>
            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 5, 8)"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="row6">

            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 6, 1)"></td>
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 6, 2)"></td>
            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 6, 3)"></td>
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 6, 4)"></td>
            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 6, 5)"></td>
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 6, 6)"></td>
            <td  class="white" onclick="place(this, 6, 7)"></td>
            <td  class="black" onclick="place(this, 6, 8)"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="row7">
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 7, 1)"></td>
            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 7, 2)"></td>
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 7, 3)"></td>
            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 7, 4)"></td>
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 7, 5)"></td>
            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 7, 6)"></td>
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 7, 7)"></td>
            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 7, 8)"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="row8">

            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 8, 1)"></td>
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 8, 2)"></td>
            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 8, 3)"></td>
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 8, 4)"></td>
            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 8, 5)"></td>
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 8, 6)"></td>
            <td class="white" onclick="place(this, 8, 7)"></td>
            <td class="black" onclick="place(this, 8, 8)"></td>

        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please pare down the code to the section(s) that are giving you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `domObj.innerHTML="Q";` in the **`place function`**, you have to do some changes in css too.

I have created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xqag3/1/)